# Installing R on Ubuntu

Tags: r

I don't know if this is the right StackExchange for this question, but I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to install R, but all the guides I get are really painful and involve long and complicated descriptions of guides I can't find my way around in. Does anyone know an easy guide to install R that I can just follow the steps and get things done?

Comment: Installation instructions are available from CRAN, http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html.

Comment: ...Can anyone explain why is this off-topic at all? @chl : By the way, the page you just linked me is the kind of horrible page I get lost in while trying to install, and the answers I got were perfectly relevant to my question.

Comment: Well, basically this site is about data analysis and statistical modeling, as described in our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), and not about software issues.

Comment: @chl : Beginning the question with "I don't know if this is the right StackExchange for this question" should generate less hate than that. Anyway, I'm still glad I had answers.

Comment: Sorry, Patrick, but I don't see any evidence of heinous behavior on this thread. Votes aim at discriminating good from bad questions, and they also help to signal off-topic questions as defined in our FAQ. This ought to be an objective assessment, and I believe it is clearly the case here. Alternatively, you can try browsing the [r-sig-debian](http://bit.ly/UmXhKB) list or post directly there for deeper discussion (as @Dirk once [said](http://bit.ly/UmX9ej)). FYI, your question was just closed, not deleted, and I for one upvoted the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the bash terminal by pressing together CTRL+ALT+T and copy and paste the following commands, line by line:

```
cd ~/Documents/
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 > rkey.txt
sudo apt-key add rkey.txt
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)/"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev
```

This set of codes is also presented here: http://wiki.lshtm.ac.uk/fsg/index.php5/Linux

Answer (score 1):

When I've been on Uni I installed RKWard

The easiest thing you can do: open Ubuntu Software Centre. Type in RKWard. Install it.

Yo have R with nice GUI straight away. I think is even better than Tinn-r

I have just double checked. In 12.04 it install RKWard but also R `version.string R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)`. You can use it to open already written scripts, write new scripts `Ctrl+N` or `File>New>Script File`. You have a console when you execute your script.

After installation of RKWard you can also run R by simple typing `R` in terminal.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go check it out when I'll try installing later tonight :) if it works I'll check your answer =D